# How to configure DHCP relay when NAT is also used?

Tags: dhcp, nat, pxe-boot, dnsmasq, openwrt

I have a multi-homed application server that serves multiple networks that are not connected with each other (other than being all connected to the server, each one on its dedicated network interface). Some of these networks have duplicate addressing, ie. there may be two completely different networks that use 10.10.0.0/16 address space. We cannot change addressing of these networks, so in that case we connect one of them to the server via static one-to-one NAT, so that from the server point of view the network is for example 10.90.0.0/16. Because the server should have a fixed, predefined address within the network (say, 10.10.0.100), both destination and source NAT is used, so the NATed network can access the server using address 10.10.0.100 like there was no NAT.

Until now, everything works fine using just iptables on the NATing machine. But we need to add the functionality to network boot some machines in the NATed network via PXE. The boot/DHCP server will be of course the muti-homed server in question, so I guess a DHCP relay needs to be added on the NAT machine.

I don't know how to configure the relay so that NAT will be taken into account as well, ie. a machine requesting DHCP will be pointed to 10.10.0.100 as DHCP server and boot source, but will in fact communicate over NAT with the server on the other side.

The machine doing NAT is a VM running OpenWRT, so a solution using dnsmasq (which is installed by default in OpenWRT) would be preferred. I know dnsmasq can act as DHCP relay, but I don't quite understand the parameters to configure this feature.

Of course if a specific configuration of the DHCP server itself, that for example involves sending to clients already transformed (NATed or unNATed) IP addresses, is required, that's acceptable as well.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

**Edit:** I thought the above description is clear enough, but from the answer provided I see it's not, so I have included a picture illustrating how it is working now. The server serves multiple networks on multiple interfaces, from which two, with duplicate address spaces, are shown here. In both networks the main server is - and should be - seen under the IP address 10.10.0.100.

There's no problem with providing DHCP/PXE to Network 1 that is connected directly.
The question is, what to put on the NAT machine and (if needed) how to reconfigure the DHCP server on the **main server** (NOT on the NAT machine) to make DHCP/PXE work also for Network 2 ?
[image]

The NAT configuration looks like this. On the main server, routing to all NATed networks (including 10.90.0.0/16) is directed to gateway 192.168.200.100 - this is the IP address of the interface of the NAT machine that is connected to the main server. Connected interface on the main server has IP address 192.168.200.1 (I didn't include these addresses on the picture). The sample iptables rules for one NATed network look like this:

```
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.200.1/32 -d 10.90.0.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 10.10.0.0/16
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.1/32 -d 10.10.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
-A PREROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -d 10.10.0.100/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -d 192.168.200.1/32 -j NETMAP --to 10.90.0.0/16
```

The goal is to allow the server to access the network 10.10.0.0/16 as if it were 10.90.0.0/16, and vice versa - the machines in network 10.10.0.0/16 to access the server as if it were 10.10.0.100. So both source and destination NAT is used here. On packets going from 192.168.200.1 towards network 10.90.0.0/16, source is changed to 10.10.0.100 and destination mapped appropriately to network 10.10.0.0/16. On packets going from network 10.10.0.0/16 towards 10.10.0.100, source is mapped to network 10.90.0.0/16 and destination changed to 192.168.200.1.

Comment: Is the application server running linux? If it were me I would probably forgo the virtual machine solution and use a network namespace to do the NATing instead, then you could even run your dhcp server right inside that namespace

Comment: Yes, the application server is running Linux. Even if we change the NATing to network namespaces (I don't know how to do it as I never used them), I guess it still doesn't change the question how to do NAT and DHCP/PXE together. DHCP server must run on the main server as it is a part of a bigger environment which provides boot images per-machine.

Comment: A process running in a network namespace is running in the same environment as all other processes, *except* for the networking (interfaces, IP forwarding rules, iptables, and so on). So depending on what parts of the environment you need, it might be worth looking into a netns could work for you. Your original question is still interesting so I might look into it if I have some free time, it's the kind of problem I love, but no immediate answer off the top of my head

Comment: Is the "main server" the only server providing dhcp on these networks?

Comment: Yes, it will be, because DHCP server will work as a part of a bigger boot/install environment that will be running there, which is developed independently. That environment will be providing appropriate boot/install images as parameters to DHCP server. Of course we can have some influence on parameters provided to DHCP server (for example IP addresses), if this is needed.

Comment: Can you share the configuration you're using on the NAT device in a bit more detail?

Comment: @RobbieMckennie I have added details to the question, below the image.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I'd reconstructed from your description but I just wanted to double check

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would make a seperate vlan/network/subnet for tftp/boot. For booting configurations cloudinit is something also to consider.

Create a custom script in /etc/firewall.user with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <OUTGOING_INTERFACE> -p udp --dport 67:68 -j MASQUERADE
chmod +x /etc/firewall.user
```

Replace <OUTGOING_INTERFACE> with the name of your outgoing network interface, such as eth0 or wan.

For the dnsmasq config see here for an tftp/boot example.
https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration

```
uci set dhcp.linux="boot"
uci set dhcp.linux.filename="/tftpboot/pxelinux.0"
uci set dhcp.linux.serveraddress="192.168.1.2"
uci set dhcp.linux.servername="fileserver"
uci add_list dhcp.linux.dhcp_option="option:root-path,192.168.1.2:/data/netboot/root"
uci commit dhcp
service dnsmasq restart
```

*Direct BOOTP requests to the TFTP server. Tell the client to load pxelinux.0 from the server at 192.168.1.2, and mount root from /data/netboot/root on the same server.*

By the way I would recommend opnsense instead of openwrt

Edit/Update
For dnsmasq to act as dhcp replay within openwrt do this

```
nano /etc/config/dhcp
```

Look for the section that starts with config dnsmasq. You may need to add or modify the dhcp-relay option. If it doesn't exist, you can add it. Here's an example

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option filterwin2k '0'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option nonegcache '0'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option localservice '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option nonwildcard '1'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option localservice '1'
    option nonwildcard '0'
    option port '0'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option rebind_domainfile '/etc/resolv.conf.auto'
    option localservice '0'
    option dhcp_relayservers '192.168.1.1'  # Replace with your main server's IP
```

Restart dnsmasq. Keep in mind that you need a recent openwrt build for this to work.

Comment: I understand that the above settings for dhcp options are for the case when dnsmasq acts as a standalone DHCP server. As I said, the DHCP server will be the main multihomed server, because of integrated boot/install environment that will be running there, is developed independently and out of scope of this question. I need dnsmasq on the NAT machine work only as a DHCP relay. If any changes to DHCP options are needed, they need to be made on the main multihomed server. The use case is very specific and I need a very specific answer tailored exactly to that use case.

Comment: Ok I understand I will edit my post.

Comment: There's a lot of options listed in your dnsmasq config, some of them are repeated multiple times, some of them are contradicting values for the same option. How can this work?